# How to enforce that a file has to have the name of its contained element (class, interface, enum ...)

Tags: c#, resharper, naming-conventions, fxcop, stylecop

we are using ReSharper, FxCop and StyleCop on our projects and I'm trying to find a way to enforce the naming of the file to be the same as the name of the contained element.

Do you know if it is possible with the mentioned tools? I cannot find anything related with this (which seems a pretty common rule to me) and we already had some problems by a violation of this rule.

Regards.

Comment: Did you check https://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule ?

Comment: You could write your own rule for StyleCop or FxCop.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by the word "file"; is this a .cs file or an entire .dll/.exe assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own custom FxCop (or StyleCop) rule. I have written an (fxcop) example of what you could look into.

This checks all types in the assembly for nested types (say a class which contains structs), I think you need something similar. Use [introspector](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/introspector.html) to develop the rule according to your own liking.

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(TypeNode type)
{
    foreach (TypeNode nestedType in type.NestedTypes)
    {
        if (nestedType.NodeType == NodeType.Struct)
            if(!type.Name.Name.Contains("Struct"))
                Problems.Add(new Problem(new Resolution("FileNameIsIncorrect", type.Name.Name), type));

    }
    return Problems;
}
```